# php mail() works, but random empty attachment is appearing

Tags: php, exchange-server, php-5.5

I am sending an automated email from my webserver, and it is working fine...except that the email I receive (in Microsoft Outlook) has a random blank text file (ATT00001.txt) showing up.  I am NOT trying to attach anything to my outbound email.  All my searches show how to attach...and I want the opposite...how NOT to attach anything!  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks!

```
$uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
        $eol = PHP_EOL;

        $header = "From: Website Admin <".$MessageFrom.">".$eol;
        $header .= "Reply-To: ".$MessageFrom.$eol;

        //now add (optional) CC and BCC
        if($CcMessageTo!=''){ $header .= "Cc: $CcMessageTo".$eol; }
        if($BccMessageTo!=''){ $header .= "Bcc: $BccMessageTo".$eol; }

        //the next line is to request a read reciept
        if($RequestReadReceipt=='yes'){ $header .= "Disposition-Notification-To: ".$MessageFrom.$eol; }

        $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0".$eol;
        $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"";

        $message = "--".$uid.$eol;
        $message .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1".$eol;
        $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit".$eol;
        $message .= $MessageBody.$eol;
        $message .= "--".$uid.$eol;

        //add an additional parameter to help not get blocked as spam
        $AdditionalParameters = "-f$MessageFrom";

        mail($MessageTo, $MessageSubject, $message, $header, $AdditionalParameters);
```

The only thing helpful I have found is that apparently ExchangeServer does not like to see an attachment before text (though I did not think I was sending an attachment).  Here is the link I found:
http://kb.mit.edu/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=4981187

Comment: My guess is the multipart/ mix

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the issue was with Content-Type: multipart/mixed at the top in the header.  This was apparently telling the email client to expect more than just email content...and thus it was making up some filler for the missing attachment.  As soon as I changed that from

> Content-Type: multipart/mixed

to

> Content-Type: text/html

everything started working.  Of course, I also did a bunch more tweaking along the way, including the ability to add a PDF attachment if I ever need to (just as part of the troubleshooting) - so here is what I ended up with after all was tweaked. Hopefully this helps someone someday.

```
if( $Attachment )
{
    $filename = $AttachmentName;
    $file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$AttachmentSrc;
    $file_size = filesize($file);
    if($file_size > 0)
    {
        $handle = fopen($file, "r");
        $filecontent = fread($handle, $file_size);
        fclose($handle);
        $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode($filecontent));
        $IncludeAttachment = 'yes';
    }
}

$uid = md5(uniqid(time()));

$header = "From: ".$MessageFromName." <".$MessageFromEmail.">".$eol;
$header .= "Reply-To: ".$MessageFromEmail.$eol;
if($CcMessageTo!=''){ $header .= "Cc: $CcMessageTo".$eol; }
if($BccMessageTo!=''){ $header .= "Bcc: $BccMessageTo".$eol; }
if($RequestReadReceipt=='yes'){ $header .= "Disposition-Notification-To: ".$MessageFromEmail.$eol; }
$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0".$eol;
if($IncludeAttachment == 'yes')
{
    $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"";
    $message = "--".$uid.$eol;
    $message .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8".$eol;
    $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable".$eol.$eol;
    $message .= quoted_printable_encode($MessageBody).$eol;
    $message .= "--".$uid.$eol;
    $message .= "Content-Type: application/pdf; name=\"".$filename."\"".$eol;
    $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64".$eol;
    $message .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"".$eol.$eol;
    $message .= $attachment.$eol;
    $message .= "--".$uid."--";
}
else
{
    $header .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8".$eol;
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable".$eol.$eol;
    $message .= quoted_printable_encode($MessageBody).$eol;
}

$AdditionalParameters = "-f$MessageFromEmail";

mail($MessageTo, $MessageSubject, $message, $header, $AdditionalParameters);
```